# Find the value of parameter $m$ such that the equation has real solutions...

Tags: absolute-value

For which values of real parameter "m" the equation:$$\sqrt3*|\tan x+\cot x|=4m$$ has real solutions?
My only thought is that $m\gt 0$ because the right part of the equation is an absolute value which is always positive. That's the only thing I can say. I  hope you'll add some more ideas, and help me solve this exercise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$\tan x+\cot x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}
  =\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{\cos x\sin x}=\frac{2}{\sin2x}\ .$$

Comment: So $m$ can have only the following values: $(0;{\sqrt3 \over 2})$!

Comment: More or less right idea, but you need to look at the details a bit more carefully.

Comment: I got that $|m|\geq\sqrt{3}/2$...

Comment: @JohnG. The bound $\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}$ is correct but the other is not, I am afraid. Cheers.

Comment: @David I noticed that $sin2x$ gives values from -1 to 1 , thus the values of absolute function will be from 0 to 2. This means that the left part of the equation gives values from 0 to $2\sqrt3$. But not to forget, sin2x cannot be $0$ so, $x\neq {\pi\over 4}$. So M can have only values ($0;{\sqrt3\over2}$)\{$\pi\over 2$}.Is this right? Please comment if it is:)

Comment: @JohnG., I'm not sure but it looks to me as if you are multiplying when you should be dividing.  Or is it possible that there was a typo in your question?  Please check carefully and let us know.

Comment: Yes, but I am multiplying when I tend to find what values can the left part of the equation get(I multiply by $\sqrt3$, and after that, I divide by 4  the margins of the interval I've got, to find out which are the values of $m$). Isn't that right?

Comment: What values can $|\sin2x|$ have?  What do you get if you divide $\sqrt3/2$ by these values?

Comment: |sin2x| can have values only from 0 to 1. |2/sin2x| can have values  from 0 to 2 . and finally $\sqrt3|{2\over sin2x}|$ can have values from 0 to $2\sqrt 3$. Sorry for keeping you so much with my exercise.

Comment: No, $|2\sin2x|$ has values from $0$ to $2$.  But $|2/\!\sin2x|$ is different.